# How to import a function from external JS file in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use an external JS function into a vue file.

#### Js file contains the method:

```
let calculateDiscount = {
  PriceAfterDiscount(price, discountPercentage) {
    const discountAmount = (discountPercentage * price) / 100;
    return price - discountAmount;
  }
};
export default calculateDiscount;
```

#### Vue file

```
<template>
 <div v-for="product in product_data" :key="product.id">
    <h4> ${{ Discount(product.price, product.sale) }}</h4>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import CalculateDiscount from "@/utilities/CalculateDiscount";        //js file containing the method
  name: "ShowProduct",
  methods: {
    Discount(){
      CalculateDiscount.PriceAfterDiscount();
    }
  }

</script>
```

I far I guess I can't import the function in method property in the right manner. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `calculateDiscount` object like:

```
let calculateDiscount = {
  PriceAfterDiscount: (price, discountPercentage) => {
    const discountAmount = (discountPercentage * price) / 100;
    return price - discountAmount;
  }
};
```

and then `CalculateDiscount.PriceAfterDiscount();` should work fine.

In the template, you had called `Discount` function with two params like:

```
{{Discount(product.price,product.sale)}}
```

but in actual code you had passed nothing:

```
methods: {
   Discount() {
      calculateDiscount.PriceAfterDiscount();
   }
}
```

Also, you have passed nothing to `calculateDiscount.PriceAfterDiscount()`. You need the pass the values from template to this and also return the result, otherwise it will never print nothing in UI:

```
methods: {
   Discount(price, sale) {
      return calculateDiscount.PriceAfterDiscount(price, sale);
   }
}
```

Comment: I updated the object as you suggested. it shows me "vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" found in" error.

Comment: Could you please create a small demo in codesandbox or codepen to show the issue happening.

Comment: here is the code demo 
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-sanderson-3h9h5?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: It seems the demo is not updated, as `calculateDiscount` or `PriceAfterDiscount` is not declare anywhere or used anywhere?

Comment: can you please recheck the demo?

Comment: Your code works fine now. In template you had called `Discount` function with two params like `Discount(product.price,product.sale)` but in actually code you had passed nothing `methods: {
    Discount() {`. Also, you have to return the `calculateDiscount.PriceAfterDiscount()` result otherwise it will never print anything in UI. [Updated Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-pasteur-gwy2z?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript modules work as namespaces and don't need additional object literal or class to be wrapped around exports.

`PriceAfterDiscount` doesn't rely on `calculateDiscount` members and doesn't need to be defined as a part of it.

It can be:

```
export function PriceAfterDiscount(price, discountPercentage) {
    const discountAmount = (discountPercentage * price) / 100;
    return price - discountAmount;
  }
};
```

And imported like:

```
import { PriceAfterDiscount } from "@/utilities/CalculateDiscount"; 

PriceAfterDiscount(...);
```

Or if it needs a namespace:

```
import * as calculateDiscount from "@/utilities/CalculateDiscount"; 

calculateDiscount.PriceAfterDiscount(...);
```